# How to make OnlyOffice and Community Document Server from Nextcloud apps work with self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, self-signed, nextcloud, onlyoffice

I have running Nextcloud in docker-compose from this example [docker-compose](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/tree/master/.examples/docker-compose/insecure/mariadb/fpm)

```
sudo docker compose exec --user www-data app php occ  -V                                                                                                                                                      

Nextcloud 26.0.3

sudo docker compose exec --user www-data app php occ  app:list

- documentserver_community: 0.1.13
- onlyoffice: 7.8.0
```

OnlyOffice and Community Document work fine without SSL certificate

After that, I generate signed SSL certificate

OnlyOffice and Community Document work fine with signed SSL certificate

But in my case, I need to work with self-signed SSL certificate

But I still have the problem

```
sudo docker compose exec --user www-data app php occ onlyoffice:documentserver --check                                                                                                                        

Error connection: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://localhost/apps/documentserver_community/healthcheck
```

```
curl --insecure  https://localhost/apps/documentserver_community/healthcheck                                                                                                                                  
true
```

I try to add to nextcloud/config/config.php

```
  'onlyoffice' =>array(
  'verify_peer_off'=>true
  ),
```

and also try add my certificate to nextcloud

```
sudo docker compose exec --user www-data app php occ  security:certificates                                                                                                                                   

+---------------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------+-----------+
| File Name     | Common Name | Organization             | Valid Until    | Issued By |
+---------------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------+-----------+
| localhost.crt |             | Internet Widgits Pty Ltd | March 12, 2029 |           |
+---------------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a self signed certificate? SSL certificates are free of charge these days.

Answer (score 0):

##### 1st way

Log into your onlyoffice container with:

```bash
docker exec -it <container> bash
```

and edit the config file `/etc/onlyoffice/documentserver/default.json`. Find the entry `"rejectUnauthorized": true` and set it to `false`:

```
},
      "requestDefaults": {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
      }
```

After that, exit and restart container:

```bash
docker container <container> stop && docker container <container> start
```

##### 2nd way

> **ATTENTION:** The Parameter must be set to **true** (not 'false')! It's a little bit confusing at this point.

The more elegant way is it to start the container directly with the parameter
`-e USE_UNAUTHORIZED_STORAGE=true`. Example:

```bash
docker run -i -t -d -p 8888:80 -p 8443:443 --name=onlyoffice --restart=always -e USE_UNAUTHORIZED_STORAGE=true onlyoffice/documentserver:latest
```